# mmap'ed file - determine which page is dirty

Tags: linux, x86-64, mmap

I've a fixed size file. The file has been ftruncate()'ed to a size = N * getpagesize(). The file has fixed size records. I've a writer process which maps the entire file by mmap(...MAP_SHARED...) and modifies records randomly (accessed like an array). I've a reader process which also does mmap(...MAP_SHARED...). Now the reader process needs to determine which page has changed in its mapping because of writer process writing to a random record. Is there a way to do it in userspace? I'm on Linux - x86_64. Platform specific code/hacks are welcome. Thank you for your time.

Edit: I have no liberty to modify the writer process' code to give me an indication of the modified records in some way.

Answer (score 6):

Relevant documentation:

1. http://lwn.net/Articles/230975/
2. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt

   - Determine the number of your virtual page (i.e. divide by 4096), multipy by 8, and seek to that position in `/proc/*/pagemap`
   - Read 8 bytes, this is the page frame number (PFN)
   - Open `/proc/kpageflags`, and seek to the PFN, read 8 bytes
   - If the `DIRTY` flag is set, the page is dirty (in other words, the writer has written to it)
   - Repeat for each page in your mapped file

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be very, very ugly. Most likely, it's just not worth trying to do this and you're better off changing whatever painted you into this corner.

You can use a shared bitmap protected by a lock. The writer protects each page. If it writes into a protected page, it faults. You'll have to catch the fault, unprotect the page, lock the bitmap, and set the bit corresponding to that bit in the bitmap. This will tell the reader that the page was modified.

The reader operates as follows (this is the painful part):

1. Lock the bitmap.
2. Make a list of modified pages.
3. Communicate that list of modified pages to the writer. The writer must protect those pages again and clear their bits in the bitmap. The writer must wait for the reader to complete this before its starts reading or changes can be lost.
4. The reader can now read the modified pages.

Comment: Then you will have to use techniques like tracing and code injection. Very, very ugly.